# Labeled, horizontal arrows pointing into a vertical line

Tags: matlab, plot, transfer-function

I'm trying to plot some annotations to go along with my step function graphs. I currently have these graphs, and I've been trying to figure out how to draw horizontal arrows that point towards vertical lines. I will also need labeled, vertical lines that are pointing towards horizontal lines.

I have attached an image that shows (in red) what I mean. I've tried the annotation() function, but it's truly a pain to get the arrows where I want them to be. If anyone wouldn't mind explaining how to use that function, or alternative methods for what I'm trying to achieve, that would be amazing!

[image: Matlab Plot with arrows I would like to achieve.]

EDIT: Is there a way to edit the Quiver arrowhead size?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using Quiver in a 2D Subplot

Not quite sure if this is any better or simpler but I used the `quiver()` function to plot the lines shown below. The `quiver()` function takes in a few inputs in this case. In the full script below I used twice the amount of `quiver()` calls to plot overlapping arrows to create a double headed arrow.

[image: Quiver Arrow Annotations]

---

### Function Call:

```
quiver(Start_Point(1),Start_Point(2),X_Displacement,Y_Displacement,0);
```

• `Start_Point` → equal to `[x y]` (**x-coordinate** **y-coordinate**)
• `Start_Point(1)` → The **x-coordinate** of the arrow's start
• `Start_Point(2)` → The **y-coordinate** of the arrow's start
• `X_Displacement` → The horizontal distance from the start of the array 
• `Y_Displacement` → The vertical distance from the start of the array

---

### Setting the Maximum Size of the Arrow Head:

The maximum size of the arrow head can be set by using the `'MaxHeadSize'` property.

```
clf;
Start_Point(1) = 0;
Start_Point(2) = 0;
X_Displacement = 0; Y_Displacement = 10;
Magnitude = sqrt(X_Displacement.^2 + Y_Displacement.^2);

quiver(Start_Point(1),Start_Point(2),X_Displacement,Y_Displacement,0,'Color','r','MaxHeadSize',1/Magnitude);
hold on 

Start_Point(1) = 0;
Start_Point(2) = 0;
X_Displacement = 100; Y_Displacement = 0;
Magnitude = sqrt(X_Displacement.^2 + Y_Displacement.^2);
quiver(Start_Point(1),Start_Point(2),X_Displacement,Y_Displacement,0,'Color','r','MaxHeadSize',1/Magnitude);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @Cory No problem, happy to help.

Comment: I was able to get the arrows to work out, but for some of my functions the arrowheads are huge. Is there a way to make them a certain size? I edited the initial post with an example.

Comment: Using the `MaxHeadSize` property may help. I added a script in my answer that tries to normalize this according to the magnitude/length of the arrow since the arrow head is proportional to its length.